# ontouchlistener isn't working

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

My image is moving weirdly and pausing at random moments while I need it to be continuous. It stops and then works. Please post if you can make it more efficient. Also look if there is a way to shorten the code.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public int x;
public float g =10.0f;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ImageView iconss = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.craft);
        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left);
        final TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fail);
        final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Right);

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                g = g + 10f;
                x = 1;

                final CharSequence work;
                work = "it is working";
                txt1.setText(work);

                iconss.setTranslationX(g);
            }

        });

        button2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
                g = g + 10f;
                x = 1;

                final CharSequence work;
                work = "it is working";
                txt1.setText(work);

                iconss.setTranslationX(g);

                return false;
            }
        });

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                g = g - 10f;
                x = 1;

                final CharSequence work;
                work = "it is working";
                txt1.setText(work);

                iconss.setTranslationX(g);
            }
        });

        button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
                g = g - 10f;
                x = 1;

                final CharSequence work;
                work = "it is working";
                txt1.setText(work);

                iconss.setTranslationX(g);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is ambiguous between ClickEvent and TouchEvent.

Your should remove TouchListener and replace them by Animation

1. Calculate the target position the image will move to
2. Set transition time
3. Start animation when button is clicked